# Generating a subdomain wrecks url's with IP?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain, configuration-files

On my site until today these 2 URLS gave me the same result:

> www.mysite.com/test.jpg
>
> 10.10.10.10/test.jpg

(where 10.10.10.10 is my static IP address)

Today I used cPanel to generate a new subdomain (**blog**.mysite.com) and since then

> 10.10.10.10/test.jpg

resolves to

> www.mysite.com/**blog**/test.jpg

(which doesn't exist)

My ISP tech support says that by default any new subdomain comes on top in the apache conf file, so by making a new subdomain it gets inserted when calling URLs by IP.

What would be the best way to get back to the original functionality?
I can't edit the server conf files but can edit my own htaccess.

Comment: Can you use mod_rewrite? I'm considering rewriting all IP requests to 'www.mysite.com' requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrite. Try placing this in an .htaccess file in your document root (for the blog.mysite.com site)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^10.10.10.10$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or replace the `R=301` flag with `P` if you really don't want to redirect the browser.

Comment: So it HAS to go to the blog subdomain first, to be mod-rewrited to the main domain? I must say I'm suprised (and disappointed at apache) that adding a subdomain wrecks something unrelated. Thanks for your help. Your solution seems to solve the issue.

Comment: @Henry It isn't so much that the adding of the subdomain wrecks things. It's just that a vhost for `10.10.10.10` was never created, so apache tries to "guess" which vhost it should use to serve the request. Technically, `10.10.10.10` shouldn't work in the first place because it's not defined.